# Relative rates of two acyclic dienes in the Diels-Alder reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, kinetics, conformers, pericyclic

As for factors that affect the rate of the Diels Alder reaction, having an s-*cis* conformation is primary.

But in a case as shown below, what makes the second diene react faster compared to the third?

The only reason I can think of is that the second diene has substituents pointing outward so they cause less steric hindrance as it reacts with a dienophile thus has a lower activation barrier. Are there any other underlying reasons apart from hindrance? [image]

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that the having the diene in an s-*cis* conformation is extremely important.  **Only from this conformation can the Diels-Alder occur.** If there is a high concentration of the s-*cis* conformer the Diels-Alder will likely occur rapidly; if there is a low concentration the reaction will occur more slowly.

In cyclopentadiene, the diene component has no choice, it is **locked** in an s-*cis* conformation by the ring.  However with acyclic 1,3-dienes an equilibrium exists between the s-*cis* and s-*trans* conformations.

In 1,3-butadiene the amount of the s-*cis* conformation is relatively small (~2%) because of the steric interaction between the "internal" hydrogens at the ends of the chain in this conformation. In accord with this expectation, 1,3-butadiene is not as reactive as cyclopentadiene in the Diels-Alder reaction.

[image]

If we replace one of these "internal" hydrogens with a methyl group (penta-1,*cis*-3-diene), the steric interaction between the "internal" methyl and hydrogen in the s-*cis* conformation is even greater, further destabilizing the s-*cis* conformation and reducing the amount present at equilibrium.  On the other hand, replacing one of the "exterior" hydrogens with a methyl group (penta-1,*trans*-3-diene) doesn't cause any increased steric interference in the s-*cis* conformation and the amount of the s-*cis* conformer is about the same as 1,3-butadiene. Again, in accord with expectations, penta-1,*trans*-3-diene reacts at a rate similar to 1,3-butadiene, whereas penta-1,*cis*-3-diene reacts slower.

[image]

([image source](http://research.cm.utexas.edu/nbauld/conjdienes.htm))

Using this information we can make predictions for your compounds. We would expect cyclopentadiene to react the fastest because it is held in an s-*cis* conformation. In the case of *cis*, *cis*-2,4-hexadiene we now have an internal methyl-methyl interaction, which severely destabilizes the s-*cis* conformation, so there is very little present at equilibrium and this compound reacts the slowest in the Diels-Alder reaction. *trans*, *trans*-2,4-hexadiene only has an "internal" hydrogen-hydrogen interaction when in the s-*cis* conformation, therefore it should react about as fast as 1,3-butadiene - in between the extreme rates of the other two compounds.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed steric hindrance. It looks a lot less severe in the picture than it actually is. Remember that each end of the line is not just a carbon atom but a methyl group $\ce{CH3}$. That means that there are three further undrawn atoms bonded to the final atom of each side of the chain.

Now making the simplistic assumption that $\ce{C-H}$ bonds are similar in length to $\ce{C-C}$ bonds and just boldly drawing the hydrogens in a $120^\circ$ angle from those final carbons we notice that one hydrogen each would land on the carbon of the opposite end of the chain — very bad. If we twisted and turned a little, we could get around that, but all of the hydrogens would still be outstandingly close to each other. Therefore, (*Z*,*Z*)-hexa-2,4-diene will have a really hard time adopting the s-*cis* configuration.

The middle molecule, (*E*,*E*)-hexa-2,4-diene only has two hydrogens in the middle, which would hardly even notice each other.